# Firebase Invites: How to send referral code with Firebase Invites

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-invites

I want to send link with refferal code via Firebase Invites. I know what I can do it with Dynamic Links but don't know how to make it with Invites. Is it possible to change generated by Firebase Invites dynamic link to my custom dynamic link?

Also when I send standard invitation with Firebase Invites it's always open Google Play even if app is installed. Can I change it?

Comment: Have answered the main part of your question below. I suggest you make a new question for always opening Google Play, since the links are meant to directly open in your app!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the invite ID as the referral code?

For example, inside `onActivityResult`:

```
val ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data!!)
```

You can then send these to your server, and you know they are user x inviting user y, and as such are referral codes.

---

Alternatively, you could use the deeplink functionality to link to a specific part of your app (e.g. `/referral/X12345`), thus retaining your existing referral codes.